# Odd behavior in C++ program

Tags: c++, input

I am writing a program that I allow the user to specify an input file to open and when I test with incorrect file names, the program is behaving very weird and it seems to have something to do with the input buffer, but I don't know where to begin other than using `getline()` instead of `cin >>` but I have already tried that.

here is the code that I think may be the problem:

```
bool openfile(ifstream&);
string userInput();

int main()
{
   // ...

   while (!openfile(inputFile))
      openfile(inputFile);

   string input = userInput();

   // ...
}

bool openfile(ifstream &inputFile)
{
   string filename;

   cout << "Please enter the name of the file or type quit to exit the program: ";
   cin >> filename;
   cout << endl;
   if (filename == "quit")
      exit(4);
   else
      inputFile.open(filename);

   if (!inputFile) 
   {
      cout << "The file \"" << filename << "\" could not be opened or does not exist.\n";
      return false; 
   }
   return true;

}

string userInput()
{
   string englishSentence;
   cout << "Please enter a sentence or type quit to exit the program: \n";
   getline(cin, englishSentence);
   if (englishSentence == "quit")
      exit(4);
   return englishSentence;
}
```

Those are the two functions that read any input. `openfile()` is called first as you can see. Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if you suspect something else in my code and I will paste it.

Comment: What is your question? You should test if the filename string is a filename because you might not want to be opening random files.

Comment: You ptobably missed calling `inputFile.clear()` whenever `inputFile.open()` failed.

Comment: You know if your second (nested) call to `openFile` succeeds, you'll ignore that and call `openFile` again, right? Your while loop should probably have nothing in the body (just replace the inner call with `;`)

Comment: You'll also probably want a `cin.ignore(...)` when switching from formatted to line based input to make sure you're starting with a clean slate.

Comment: where is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (!openfile(inputFile))
      openfile(inputFile);
```

What this does is attempt to open the file twice each iteration, as long as the first attempt fails. Also, you need to make sure that `inputFile` is closed before attempting to open it again since it appears that you're reusing the same file object repeatedly.

Certainly first try something like:

```
while (!openfile(inputFile))
      ;
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thank you and the others that found this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
while (!openfile(inputFile));
```

Since the way you have it it would request an input filename twice if it fails the first time.

Basically to outline the problem:

#### Begin Loop

- Request Filename
- Invalid Filename

  - Request Replacement Filename
  - Return to start of the loop (Checks again)

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I see from your code:

1. `int main(); { ... }` does not define the `main` function. You need to drop the semicolon, or it won't even compile.
2. `while (!openfile(inputFile)) openfile(inputFile);` repeats `openfile(inputFile)` unnecessarily. If the first one (in the condition) fails and the second one (in the body) succeeds, a third call will be made (in the condition) to check if the loop should continue. What you probably want is just `while (!openfile(inputFile)) { }`.
3. You open a file in `openfile` and never use it in the subsequent `userInput`.

Comment: Thank you, #2 is the solution. 1) Was a typo when posting. 3) not necessary for this program.